# Replace with a different segment

Tags: scripting

I have a code which is having around 6000 lines in C++.
As a part of code refactoring, I'm required to modify all the output lines in this code.

Eg:

Currently, existing lines look like this -

```
cout<<"The string value is - " << sStringVal;
```

My modification is to add the class name in each cout statement, like -

```
cout<<"CFlowController: The string value is - "<< sStringVal;
```

> There are around 3900 output lines which require this change. Can
>   anyone suggest a script or how to do this apart from the manual
>   replacement?

Comment: Use find and replace using regex in VSCode or any other IDE

Comment: @BlackMamba thanks a lot sir :) I'm using eclipse luna, will this work??

Comment: Yes it should work in any modern IDE